# Prevent another command from exiting Windows CLI

Tags: windows, command-line-interface

I am trying to build a Windows .bat script that includes several commands:

```
ionic state restore
ECHO done restoring state
```

However, the "ionic state restore" command appears to be exiting out of my control so that I do not see the ECHO or any subsequent steps.

Is there a way to run this in silent mode or in some way I can continue on after it is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution with CALL:

> The CALL command will launch a new batch file context along with any specified parameters. When the end of the second batch file is reached (or if EXIT is used), control will return to just after the initial CALL statement.

**Source**: http://ss64.com/nt/call.html

So running the following works great:

```
CALL ionic state restore
ECHO done restoring state
```